# How to show a function is Lebesgue measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose that $f: U\times \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R$ is a measurable function where $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a measurable set. Also let $K\subseteq \mathbb R^m$ is a compact set.
>
> Then prove that the set $$\Phi(x)=\sup\{ |f(x,u)-f(x,v)|:u,v\in K, ||u-v||<1\} ,\text{ for all }x\in U$$
> is a measurable function.

Everything is taken as **Lebesgue measure**.

I know that if we take supremum over the countable number of measurable functions then the function is measurable.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I don't think  this is true. Can  you provide some context for this question?

Comment: I have seen it in the proof of 'Scorza-Dragoni' Theorem. Actually, I have a note on this in hard copy so I can't send any link. In the proof of the  'Scorza-Dragoni' Theorem, this type of functions has been used in Egorov's Theorem.  The sequence of functions for Egorov Theorem is taken as $\Phi_j(x)$ and $||u-v||<\frac{1}{j}$.